# Language selection for my English news app in Android studio (Switch between English news to Hindi News)

Tags: php, android, android-studio

I have a news app in English and I want to Show the news in hindi laguage also. How to do it in android studio?

Answer (score 0):

If i get your question right you could use the translation editor to add a Hindi translation.

You can access the translation editor by right clicking on the string.xml and selecting translation editor.